# Send and Cancel button of twitter sharekit don't appear

Tags: ios4, twitter, sharekit

good morning
i used sharekit twitter and it's worked good but the send and the cancel button don't appera. I explain more  i have two classes the first have a navigation controller and his job to show two text view, the second class which contain a twitter second code

http://cl.ly/2B0C3G031W0A2t2C0C3h
http://cl.ly/1s361l2I2L1Q061N3O2b

you see there is no send button and cancel

Answer (score 1):

try to add this in your viewDidLoad : `[SHK setRootViewController:myViewController];`

Answer (score 0):

since ShareKit is on GitHub, it might be a good idea to check in the issues area. Here is a thread about the issue:

https://github.com/ideashower/ShareKit/issues/254

Hope that helps.

Comment: think you but i discovered the probleme i explain: the navigation bar of on other class hide te navigation bar of the sharekit twitter and mail which is controlled by a sub view class of this class. if you can help me how i can hide the navigation bar of this class from the sub view

Answer (score 0):

check this diff

Classes/ShareKit/Core/SHK.m

https://github.com/ideashower/ShareKit/commit/e741af1f120faab2342e1811c17d649a06f922d4

it worked for me.